# Use automatic separator for CONCAT?

Tags: sparql, rdf, concatenation

My query starts like this:

```
SELECT
      #MIN(?dateYear) AS     ?dateYears)
      (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT     ?dateYear ; separator = ", ") AS     ?dateYears)
      (CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gameENLabel; separator = ", ") ,", ", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gameJALabel; separator = ", "), ", ", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?hepburnLabel; separator = ", "), ", ", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gameZHLabel; separator = ", "), ", ", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?pinyinLabel; separator = ", ")) as ?wookie)
      (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT     ?dataLink ; separator = ", ") AS     ?dataLinks)
      #(?game AS ?dataPages)
      (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT     ?wikiLink ; separator = ", ") AS     ?wikiLinks)
      (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT     ?wikiName ; separator = ", ") AS     ?wikiNames)

      WHERE {
          ...
      }
```

It works, but when `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gameJALabel; separator = ", ")` returns an empty spring, the comma immediately following it is still rendered. Can the CONCAT command be supplied with a separator that only gets rendered if the preceding command returns something? Is there a better way to do all this that I don't know about? Thanks!

Comment: What else should happen here? You're simply calling `CONCAT` on a bunch of strings produced by `GROUP_CONCAT`, each of them separated by a comma. Maybe you could call `REPLACE` with the appropriate REGEX pattern if something is not like you want: something like this (untested): `REPLACE(CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gameENLabel; separator = ", ") ,", ", GROUP_CONCAT() .... ), ", , ", ", ") AS ?wookie)`

Comment: That's a good tip. But I might have to use the replace command several times to get all the matches. For instance `", , , , "` will need two passes.

Comment: Well, REPLACE allows for a REGEX as pattern, so I'd think something like `, (, )+` could work. Again, untested ...

Comment: Yes, regex may work better,